# Virtualhost For Wildcard Subdomain and Static Subdomain

Tags: apache, subdomain, virtualhost, wildcard-subdomain

I have an odd situation where I want to have the URLs `app1.example.com`, `example.com` and `*.example.com`  all using a different virtual host.  This is what I have (excluding `example.com` because it just makes it messier).

```
<VirtualHost *>
  ServerName app1.example.com
  ServerAlias app1.example.com

  DocumentRoot = /var/www/app1
  # Other configuration for this app here

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *>
  ServerName wildcard.example.com
  ServerAlias *.example.com

  DocumentRoot = /var/www/wildcard
  # other configuration for this app here

</VirtualHost>
```

The problem is that they conflict.  Whichever one is listed first wins out. How can I host both a wildcard virtualhost and a specific one?

Note: I'm not just changing `DocumentRoot` in the config, so using `mod_rewrite` to change the DocumentRoot variable does not fix it.

Answer (score 178, accepted):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/app1
  ServerName app1.example.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/example
  ServerName example.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/wildcard
  ServerName other.example.com
  ServerAlias *.example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Should work. The first entry will become the default if you don't get an explicit match. So if you had app.otherexample.com point to it, it would be caught be app1.example.com.

Comment: Just a question, what does `NameVirtualHost *:80` do?

Comment: This directive enables the name based virtual hosts and will tell apache to listen on all ip's (*) on port 80. Apache 2.2 Docs: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/vhosts/name-based.html

Comment: Remove the `NameVirtualHost *:80`: AH00548: NameVirtualHost has no effect and will be removed in the next release

Comment: The wild card one does not work for me, do you know why?

Comment: Hi, just to add another tip I got: if you have separate files for each than make sure file names of virtual hosts is listed apathetically in the same order, such as: `00app`, `01example`, `02other`.

Comment: `NameVirtualHost *:80` is important for apache 2.2, no need for apache 2.4, I don't know why.

Comment: It's all in the order!

Comment: Does `ServerAlias` support other expressions other than `*`, like `ServerAlias a[0-5]?*.example.com`

Comment: Where do I find this file?

Comment: how to work with ssl certificate? 

`RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =example.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =*.example.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]`

Comment: Can you also use a wildcard for the TLD? E.g.:    example.*

Answer (score 32):

Wildcards can only be used in the `ServerAlias` rather than the `ServerName`. Something which had me stumped.

For your use case, the following should suffice

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAlias *.example.com
    VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/%1/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: This is a great solution but for future reference does require `a2enmod vhost_alias` for the vhost_alias module to be turned on.

Answer (score 2):

This also works for https needed a solution to making project directories this was it. because chrome doesn't like non ssl anymore used free ssl. Notice: My Web Server is Wamp64 on Windows 10 so I wouldn't use this config because of variables unless your using wamp.

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerAdmin test@test.com
ServerName test.com
ServerAlias *.test.com

SSLEngine On
SSLCertificateFile "conf/key/certificatecom.crt"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "conf/key/privatecom.key"

VirtualDocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/subdomains/%1/"

DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/subdomains"
<Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/subdomains/">
    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>
```