# Virtual host and subdomains on Wamp windows

Tags: virtualhost

I want to create virtual host and sub-domains for that host on local machine such that my localhost serve as a website like I do not need to write localhost in url bar:

```
localhost  ---> mysite.com
           ---> sd1.mysite.com
           ---> sd2.mysite.com
```

actually I am using wordpress plugin **WP Subdomains** which makes sub-domain for main categories like.

```
cat1.localhost
cat2.localhost
```

but if we try to access **cat1.localhost** browser error **Server not found** which is definitely because we did not create sub-domain named **cat1** for localhost.

I google but no solution found which exactly solve my problem.

I also followed http://www.talkphp.com/general/2170-setup-sub-domain-wamp.html

but following error appear:

> **Internal Server Error**
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator, admin@localhost and inform
>   them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done
>   that may have caused the error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
>   log.

Answer (score 2):

Okay got it....

I followed http://www.talkphp.com/general/2170-setup-sub-domain-wamp.html but skip step 3:

```
Open up: C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.2.6\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf.
```

and in `httpd.conf` comment `DocumentRoot "E:/wamp/www/"` and add

```
DocumentRoot "E:/wamp/www/wordpress"
```

and it work. :)

Comment: Not only is it broken, but the archive.org cache of the page points to another link that is broken, which isn't on archive.org D: But users will probably want this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16878503 and this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16878503

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the link below. I tried this and working fine for me.

http://www.axertion.com/tutorials/2012/03/how-to-setup-local-subdomains-using-wampserver/

Comment: That was very useful! Thank you so much!