# Sub domains without creating sub directory

Tags: php, url, subdomain

I have some city options in main domain which is like *www.xyzsite.com*. When a user clicks on `abc` city, I want to show it as *www.abc.xyzsite.com*. I don't want to create sub directory for every city as I don't have any city dependent file but I want to show the city related sub domain URL.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/758351/virtualhost-for-wildcard-subdomain-and-static-subdomain ?

Comment: @Zyberzero - Its apache webserver.

Comment: @MarcB - Thank you for the thread link. I'll go through that and come back.