# How create dynamic subdomain in Codeigniter 3 using MAMP Pro

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

Trying to route **https://some-username.myawesomeapp.dev** to **https://myawesomeapp.dev/User/get_details/some-username**. Could someone please tell me what is wrong with what I'm doing below?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z0-9-]+).myawesomeapp\.dev [NC]  
RewriteRule (.*) /User/get_details/%1 [L]
```

## UPDATE

some-username is dynamic. thanks

## ANOTHER UPDATE

I'm working locally using MAMP Pro.

Comment: Escape the dot before `myawesomeapp`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but didn't work. I'm working locally using MAMP, could this be the problem?

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/758351/virtualhost-for-wildcard-subdomain-and-static-subdomain) q/a, maybe helps.

Answer (score 0):

first you have to create a wildcart subdomain

eg: ***.yourdomain.com**

second
add below code to **.htaccess**

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !www.yourdomainname.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?([a-z0-9-]+). yourdomainname.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?page=%2 [NC,QSA]
```

finally

add php code in **index.php**

```
$page = $_GET['page'];
echo $page; exit;
```