# .htaccess to read internal index.php for any dynamic subdomains on server

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My new project will have dynamic sub-domain names for example:
aa.mysite.com ; ac.mysite.com and etc

How can I use a file located in mysite.com/subdomains/index.php as default index.php on any requested subdomain *.mysite.com ?

Please mind - I dont want to redirect, just to load the mentioned index.php file

Please help, Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

I guess this isn't possible with .htaccess, this should be done in your virtual host configuration of Apache.

Use wildcard virtualhosts to specify the documentroot for your dynamic subdomains.

A related question, not with .htaccess but for the apache configuration, is asked before:
[Virtualhost For Wildcard Subdomain and Static Subdomain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/758351/virtualhost-for-wildcard-subdomain-and-static-subdomain)