# Virtualhost For Wildcard and Static Subdomain

Tags: apache, subdomain, virtualhost, wildcard-subdomain

This is what I basically have now:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot /var/www/app1
   ServerName app1.example.com
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot /var/www/example
   ServerName example.com
   ServerAlias *.example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

This configuration makes app1.example.com a default serving VirtualHost.

Thus, when another.domain.com is pointed to *.example.com, it is served by app1.example.com.

**How this configuration can be changed, so that another.domain.com would be served by *.example.com, still having app1.example.com, *.example.com and example.com working too?**

Thank you.

*P.S. I'm basing somewhat my question on this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/758383/1319821)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My own research gave me the only workaround so far. I've ended up using another port for app1.example.com.

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
   DocumentRoot /var/www/app1
   ServerName app1.example.com
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot /var/www/example
   ServerName example.com
   ServerAlias *.example.com
</VirtualHost>
```