# Wagtail Multi-sites vs Apache Virtual Hosts

Tags: django, apache, wagtail

I've been to this site countless times but never made an account.
I'm working on my first big project, so, first question:

I intend to make a few websites that will be sharing the same droplet instance from hosting provider (DO).

Wagtail offers multiple-sites on a single codebase. It lets you manage all sites
from a single dashboard.

Apache lets you create multiple domains/individual websites - known as 'virtual hosts' - and directs the user to the specific directory where the requested website is located.

The websites I'm working on will share a single database to a certain degree (one of the sites will act as checkout page for some of the other sites, for example, where cart contents are retrieved via api/jason (I don't know yet))

Wagtail seems to be the best choice but I want to make sure Apache isn't required
regardless of how I solve this problem (ex: if DO requires apache to be able to serve my websites as opposed to directly serving from django*, for example)

*I meant in a single Apache2 instance.

tvesday

Comment: You basically want to set it up so that apache matches any subdomain, then the sites framework in django should handle things once requests hit the application. Take a look at this answer; https://stackoverflow.com/a/758383/1199464

Comment: I think I know what you mean, I'll try it. Thanks.

Comment: @markwalker It worked!.

Comment: The sites framework is pretty great isn't it!!

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this is essentially to get your web server, apache or nginx, to pass all requests from any subdomain to your django application.

Taking an example from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/758383/1199464) the apache config might look like this;

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/app1
  ServerName app1.example.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/example
  ServerName example.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/wildcard
  ServerName other.example.com
  ServerAlias *.example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Once you have a request sent to your django application the [sites framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/sites/) can translate the request into what your application is configured to do for that sub domain.

Django's `Site` object defines a name and a domain which the framework will get from the database using the request object, for example;

```py
from django.contrib.sites.shortcuts import get_current_site

def my_view(request):
    current_site = get_current_site(request)
    if current_site.domain == 'foo.com':
        # Do something
        pass
    else:
        # Do something else.
        pass
```

You can link your database models to a `Site` using `ForeignKey` or `ManyToMany` relationships depending on what suits the model.

- [Associating content with multiple sites](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/sites/#associating-content-with-multiple-sites)
- [Associating content with a single site](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/sites/#associating-content-with-a-single-site)

Generally with a multisite approach you have a settings file per site and these include a setting explicitly for `SITE_ID` to link to the site in your database.

However...

There is a django application called [`django-multisite`](https://pypi.org/project/django-multisite/) which I've used recently for a similar application which creates it's own `Site` objects. This allows you to use a single settings file by effectively creating a dynamic `SITE_ID`. I much prefer this approach, although I have found a bug when migrating from an empty database because the app queries the `Site` table, which obviously doesn't exist.
At this point I've raised the [issue](https://github.com/shestera/django-multisite/issues/6) & fixed in a fork but the package author hasn't responded.

Comment: I had never deployed before so I just thought of apache2 but I'm actually using nginx. This whole answer helps a lot though, so thx. I'm reading https://www.serverlab.ca/tutorials/linux/web-servers-linux/how-to-configure-multiple-domains-with-nginx-on-ubuntu/

Comment: @tvesday good choice. I don't think I'll ever go back to apache after moving to nginx 

Comment: Do I need to add files such as /var/www/specificdomain.com or just let gunicorn handle the request directly from project file through /var/www/html since it will serve the main project (django) via symlinks (sites-available/sites-enabled)?